# Block UI thread but keep handling incoming calls

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I'm developing a plugin for a 3D modelling application. For this application, there is also a third party plugin (a render engine) that I would like to automate.

What I do is create a list of Camera `List<Camera> cameraViews` , iterate trough all of them and tell the render engine to start rendering

```
foreach ( Camera camera in cameraViews )
{
    // tell the modellingApplication to apply camera
    modellingApplication.ApplyCameraToView(camera);

    // tell the render engine to render the image
    string path = "somePathWhereIWantToSaveTheImage"
    renderEngine.renderCurrentScene(path)

    // .renderCurrentScene() seems to be async, because my code, which is on the UI thread
    // continues... so:

    // make sure that the image is saved before continuing to the next image
    while ( !File.Exists(path) )
    {
        Thread.Sleep(500);
    }
}
```

However, this wont work. The renderingplugin seems to do some async work but, when doing this async work, it is calling the main thread for retrieving information.

I found a workaround for this: Right after calling the render engine to render, call a MessageBox. This will block the code from continuing but async calls are still beïng handled. I know, this is weird behaviour. Whats even weirder is the fact that my MessageBox gets automatically closed when the renderengine has done calling the UI thread for information and continues in his own process. Making my code continue to the while loop to check if the image is saved on the disk.

```
foreach ( Camera camera in cameraViews )
{
    // tell the modellingApplication to apply camera
    modellingApplication.ApplyCameraToView(camera);

    // tell the render engine to render the image
    string path = "somePathWhereIWantToSaveTheImage"
    renderEngine.renderCurrentScene(path)

    // .renderCurrentScene() seems to be async, because my code, which is on the UI thread
    // continues... so:

    // show the messagebox, as this will block the code but not the renderengine.. (?)
    MessageBox.Show("Currently processed: " + path);

    // hmm, messagebox gets automatically closed, that's great, but weird...

    // make sure that the image is saved before continuing to the next image
    while ( !File.Exists(path) )
    {
        Thread.Sleep(500);
    }
}
```

This is wonderful, except for the messagebox part. I don't want to show a messagebox, I just want to pause my code without blocking the entire thread (as calls from the renderengine to the ui thread are still accepted)..

It would've been much easier if the renderengine didn't do his work async..

Comment: Is there any kind of event that fires from `renderEnine` that tells you the render is done? Tell us what API you are using and we will able to help you a lot better.

Comment: what happens if you wrap your code in an `Invoke` to the UI thread?

Comment: It's fairly trivial to invoke some "wait" code on the UI thread which doesn't involve a `MessageBox`, however, I am more interested in *why* you can't just let the UI continue? Are you just waiting for `renderEngine` to finish before you clean-up the image?

Comment: I'm curious about message box auto-closing after information retrieval. Who closes it? If it's render engine then is that a documented behavior? What happens if you don't show the message box, but rather just leave current message handler after only one renderer is started?

Comment: Like any modal dialog, MessageBox has its own message loop, this is why engine continues to work. Why it is closed - you need to ask the egine authors, this is really strange effect. Be happy that your main application window is not closed...

Comment: In Windows Forms you can try to add Application.DoEvents after Sleep. It is a good idea to disable window during this process, to prevent reentrant UI handlers execution.

Comment: I do not have an api, the renderer is an unmanaged dll. The methods I have are given to me by the creator of the renderer.

Comment: @James, I can't let the UI continue (without the while loop) because then the renderengine gets told to perform a new render while it's still busy with the current one.

Comment: @Alex Farber, could you transform your comment to an answer so I can accept it? Application.DoEvents seems to do the trick.. Thank you

Comment: @Alex Farber, I can only disable my own windows but not the modellingApplication's. Is there any method to block user input for the entire thread? Because DoEvents() also gives the possibility for the user to click on any button in the native application

Comment: Why not launch the renderer on another thread? if this is an option I can show you what to do...

Answer (score 0):

I don't feel this is the best answer, but it hopefully it's what you are looking for. This is how you block a thread from continuing.

```
    // Your UI thread should already have a Dispatcher object. If you do this elsewhere, then you will need your class to inherit DispatcherObject.
    private DispatcherFrame ThisFrame;

    public void Main()
    {
        // Pausing the Thread
        Pause();
    }

    public void Pause()
    {
        ThisFrame = new DispatcherFrame(true);
        Dispatcher.PushFrame(ThisFrame);
    }

    public void UnPause()
    {
        if (ThisFrame != null && ThisFrame.Continue)
        {
             ThisFrame.Continue = false;
             ThisFrame = null;
        }
    }
```

If you want to still receive and do actions on that thread while blocking intermediately, you can do something like this. This feels, um... kinda hacky, so don't just copy and paste without making sure I didn't make some major mistake typing this out. I haven't had my coffee yet.

```
// Used while a work item is processing. If you have something that you want to wait on this process. Or you could use event handlers or something.
private DispatcherFrame CompleteFrame;
// Controls blocking of the thread.
private DispatcherFrame TaskFrame;

// Set to true to stop the task manager.
private bool Close;

// A collection of tasks you want to queue up on this specific thread. 
private List<jTask> TaskCollection;

public void QueueTask(jTask newTask)
{
    //Task Queued.

    lock (TaskCollection) { TaskCollection.Add(newTask); }
    if (TaskFrame != null) { TaskFrame.Continue = false; }
}

// Call this method when you want to start the task manager and let it wait for a task.
private void FireTaskManager()
{
    do
    {
        if (TaskCollection != null)
        {
            if (TaskCollection.Count > 0 && TaskCollection[0] != null) 
            { 
                ProcessWorkItem(TaskCollection[0]);
                lock (TaskCollection) { TaskCollection.RemoveAt(0); }
            }
            else { WaitForTask(); }
        }
    }
    while (!Close);
}

// Call if you are waiting for something to complete.
private void WaitForTask()
{
    if (CompleteFrame != null) { CompleteFrame.Continue = false; }

    // Waiting For Task.

    TaskFrame = new DispatcherFrame(true);
    Dispatcher.PushFrame(TaskFrame);
    TaskFrame = null;
}

/// <summary>
/// Pumping block will release when all queued tasks are complete. 
/// </summary>
private void WaitForComplete()
{
    if (TaskCollection.Count > 0)
    {
        CompleteFrame = new DispatcherFrame(true);
        Dispatcher.PushFrame(CompleteFrame);
        CompleteFrame = null;
    }
}

private void ProcessWorkItem(jTask taskItem)
{
    if (taskItem != null) { object obj = taskItem.Go(); }
}
```